# Getting error no such file or directory

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am compiling a very simple code and still I am getting error as

```
 1  17  E:\Education\C++ programming\Marksheet.h  [Error] string: No such file or directory
```

And most confusing thing is this error is coming in the first line which is just #include type
code is as follows:

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Marksheet
{
public:
    Marksheet(string,string);
    void setCoursename(string);
    string getCoursename();
    void dispmessage();
    void setinstname(string);
    string getinstname();

private:
    string coursename;
    string instname;     
};
```

I am using DEVC++ IDE for compiling and executing this code.
The name of the source code file is also Marksheet.cpp and its code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Marksheet.h"
using namespace std;

Marksheet::Marksheet(string cname,string instname){

    setCoursename(cname);
    setinstname(instname);
}
void Marksheet::setCoursename(string cname)
{
    coursename=cname;

}
void Marksheet::setinstname(string insname){
    instname=insname;
}
string Marksheet::getCoursename()
{
    return coursename;
}
string Marksheet::getinstname()
{
    return instname;
}
void Marksheet::dispmessage()
{
    cout<<"Welcome to the "<<coursename<<"\n";
    cout<<"This course is offered by Prof."<<instname<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried inserting a space between `#include` and `<string>`?

Comment: **If** it's picking up `iostream` but not `string` chances are you dev environment is boned. Maybe the `string` header file was inadvertently deleted. If it's not picking up either of them your project or IDE configuration may be pointing to the wrong place for standard library header files.

Comment: That's a helpful edit.  Can you add the entire compiler output to the question?  Something is very unusual.  With luck, seeing the actual g++ command being run will shed some light.